# String.replace callback not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to make a class to convert bbcode to html but replace doesn't call callback function.

Here's what i have

```
function bbcode(){
    this.bbcode_table = {};

    this.bbcode_table[/[asdf]/g] = function(match, contents, offset, input_string){
        return "hi";
    }
}

bbcode.prototype.toHTML = function(str){
    for (var key in this.bbcode_table){
        str = str.replace(key, this.bbcode_table[key]);
    }
    console.log(str); // asdf
}

var a = new bbcode;
a.toHTML("asdf");
```

The code above is not working, however, the code below works well.

```
text = "asdf";
text = text.replace(/[asdf]/g, function(match, contents, offset, input_string){
    return "hi";
});
console.log(text); // hihihihi
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `String.replace` expects a `regex` as first parameter, then it will trigger callback for each occurrence. Make sure your `key` is a `regex`

Comment: console.log(key) outputs /[asdf]/g, pretty sure it's a regex @guijob

Comment: try printing `console.log(typeof key)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `key` is converted to `string`, so the funtion `replace` is not capturing any match with `"/[asdf]/g"`.

You can follow this approach with the object `RegExp`

```js
function bbcode() {
  this.bbcode_table = {};

  this.bbcode_table["[asdf]"] = {
    "cb": function(match, contents, offset, input_string) {
      return "hi";
    },
    "flag": "g"
  }
}

bbcode.prototype.toHTML = function(str) {
  for (var key in this.bbcode_table) {
    var regex = new RegExp(key, this.bbcode_table[key].flag);
    str = str.replace(regex, this.bbcode_table[key].cb);
  }
  console.log(str);
}

var a = new bbcode;
a.toHTML("asdf");
```